# Disable apache server-status check

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

In apache access.log following lines are coming and as a result my response time metric is getting affected.How can i disable/remove these lines from access.log?

127.0.0.1 - - [10/Aug/2017:08:38:22 +0000] "localhost.****.com" "GET /server-status?auto HTTP/1.1" 200 300 291 "-" "Ruby"

Answer (score 5):

This functionality comes from a [standard module called `status`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_status.html) and so you can simply disable that module to remove the `/server-status` endpoint.

On a Debian-based server, that means running:

```
a2dismod status
```

and then restarting the web server:

```
apache2ctl configtest
systemctl restart apache2.service
```

Answer (score 1):

Comment below lines in httpd.conf

```
#<Location /server-status>
#    SetHandler server-status
#    Order deny,allow
#    Deny from all
#    Allow from localhost 127.0.0.1
#</Location>

Also is check if any cronjob is running in server.
```

Comment: Thanks.Its commented but still i will get the line only difference is that the status code will change to 400.

Comment: Is there any cronjob running in server ?